# Do we need to define our broadcast receiver in Android Manifest in case if it is Dynamic Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, publish-subscribe, android-broadcast

If we don't need to define ,then how do i set custom permissions ie "X",so that it can accept only those broadcast who is registered with "X" permission.

Answer (score -1):

you can use explicit broad cast receiver here is the reference link

https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a

Comment: Please be clear in your answer , I am not asking about implicit and explicit receivers.

Comment: if your are registering the brodcast reciver in activity dynamicaly then you dont need add it to manifest